# Removing specific item from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am using the following function to save items into an array in local storage. Once an item has been stored I want to remove it from the array by selecting the save button again. Currently users can save the same item multiple times. By modifying the save button to remove the item users will have an easy way of removing items and it will prevent them from saving the same item multiple times.

```
$('.saveButton').click(function(){
    var film = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("film"));
    var saveFilm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save") || "[]");
    saveFilm.push(film);
    localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(saveFilm));    
});
```

How should I build on the function to allow me to do this?

edit:

```
$('.saveButton').click(function(){
    var film = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("film"));
    var saveFilm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save") || "[]");
    var arrayLength = (saveFilm.length);
    $.each(saveFilm, function(index,saveFilm){
        if(saveFilm.id===film.id){
            saveFilm.splice(saveFilm.indexOf(film), 1);
            console.log("true")
        }
        else{
            saveFilm.push(film);
            console.log("false")
        }
    localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(saveFilm));
    })
});
```

edit2:

```
$('.saveButton').click(function(){
var film = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("film"));
var saveFilm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save") || "[]");
var arrayLength = (saveFilm.length);
if (arrayLength>0){
    for(i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){
        if(saveFilm[i].id===film.id){
            saveFilm.splice(saveFilm.id, 1);
        }
        else{
            saveFilm.push(film);     
        }
    }
    }else{
        saveFilm.push(film);


     }
        localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(saveFilm));
});
```

Comment: use a Set instead of the array

Comment: `Set` won't help if `film` is an object, since the two objects will look the same but won't be the same object, they can be duplicated all day long.

Comment: @samanime yeah... Too few infos to judge on that.d

Comment: If you are going to splice the array while looking for duplicates you need to iterate from back to front. If you splice iterating front to back and have duplicates one after another, you will pass over the second one. ie [1, 2, 2, 3] and you splice the first 2, you are saying splice at index 1 (where the first 2 is), move the second 2 to index 1 while incrementing the index to 2 (which will now be value 3). Your result will be [1, 2, 3].

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll just read the value back, `JSON.parse()` it, remove the element, then save it again.

If you're just adding it to the function above, just add something like this:

```
$('.saveButton').click(function(){
    var film = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("film"));
    var saveFilm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save") || "[]");

    if (!saveFilm.includes(film)) {
      saveFilm.push(film);
    } else {
      saveFilm.splice(saveFilm.indexOf(film), 1);
    }

    localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(saveFilm));    
});
```

If `film` is an object though, this won't work. Instead, you'll need to have some kind of key you can use to find the element (such as name) which you'll instead loop through the array and find. Once you find it (or don't find it), then the logic I shared will work again.

```
// assuming film.name is a valid unique identifier 
function getFilmIndex(films, film) {
   const film = films.find(f => f.name === film.name);
   return film ? null : films.indexOf(film);
}
```

Comment: film is an object, but i can use film.id as a unique identifier. I don't understand your second function but have tried to solve it my own way (see edit), though I keep getting saveFilm.push is not a fucntion error.

Comment: My second function is just a function that will return the index so you can use it in the first. For yours, I would just remove `saveFilm` from the parameters (so just `function (index)`). That second parameter probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: I have almost got it working now, if a user saves one film they can remove and add it fine. Once multiple films are saved it becomes quite inconsistent, sometimes it will duplicate films and change already saved films to the same as the one being saved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when splicing from front to end. When splicing and iterating automatically (using for loop as (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)) what ends up happening is if you have duplicates back-to-back then you will skip the duplicate.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4], toRemove = 2;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] === toRemove)
    arr.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

What happens is you get rid of the first 2, move the second where that 2 was but starting looking at 3. There are 2 ways prevents this:

**1. Manually iterate i when you do not splice an element**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4], toRemove = 2;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;){
  if(arr[i] === toRemove){
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  }else{
    i++;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

**2. Itererate in reverse order (preferred way)**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4], toRemove = 2;

for(var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
  if(arr[i] === toRemove)
    arr.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(arr);
```